# Watching which function is called in Python

Tags: python, debugging

What is the easiest way to record function calls for debugging in Python? I'm usually interested in particular functions or all functions from a given class. Or sometimes even all functions called on a particular object attribute. Seeing the call arguments would be useful, too.

I can imagine writing decorators for all that, but then I'd still have to modify the source code in different places. And writing a class decorator which modifies all methods isn't that straightforward.

Is there a solution where I don't have to modify my source code? Ideally something which doesn't slow down Python too much.

Comment: Why not use Python's [built-in debugging tools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/debug.html)?

Comment: You could monkey patch `object` itself when in 'debug mode' and reconfigure `__getattribute__`, `__setattr__`, and maybe `__call__`, then use some sort of filtering mechanism to define which things you want to log and which not.  Though @StevenRumbalski's question deserves answering first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script, if you're interested in call counts, etc.

Comment: @Steven: I only know normal pdb usage. But I'd rather have a full program run and just a report of function calls. Is there a good solution with the debugging tools?

Comment: Profile: http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ought to be able to implement something that does what you want using either [`sys.setprofile()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.setprofile) or perhaps [`sys.settrace()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.settrace). They both let you define a function to be called when specific "events" occur, like function calls, and pass additional information to which can be used to to determine the function/method being called and examine its arguments.

If you look around, there's probably sample usage code to use as a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Except decorators, for Python >= 3.0 you could use new __getattribute__ method for a class, which will be called every time you call any method of the object. 
You could look through Lutz "Learning Python" chapters 31, 37 about it.

Comment: `__getattribute__` exists in Python 2, too, as part of new-style classes introduced in Python 2.2. Not sure what you meant by "Except decorators"...